# When is it advisable to use `size_t` for array declaration or iteration in c++?

Tags: c++

Can someone explain and provide examples of situations where using `size_t` would be more beneficial than, let's say, `int` or `uint8_t` for array declarations or iteration?

Comment: More beneficial than... what?

Comment: @eerorika Let's say `int` or `uint8_t`

Comment: Better than `uint8_t` if the array might contain more than 256 elements. Better than `int` if the array might contain more than 65536 elements.

Comment: @DivyaAggarwal ... and? Why not let the rest of us know?

Comment: @JerryCoffin "_Better than `int` if the array might contain more than 65536 elements._" But `int` is 32-bit sized on any system you will encounter nowadays.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: Actually I should have said 32768. It might be larger, but it's still only required to be 16 bits.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yes, it is **required** to be 16-bits, but in practice, nowadays, I have never seen it be limited to it. Note: If we are talking  technically, the range of 16-bit `int` is from -32768 to 32767.

Comment: You may not have seen modern implementations that have a 16-bit `int`, but they do exist.   And `int` is only guaranteed to have a range of `-32767` to `32767`.   Don't make the mistake of thinking that implementations you see are the yardstick for what is required - it is the standard that defines the yardstick against which correctness of compilers and libraries are assessed, not the reverse.

Comment: Btw, `size_t` is an unsigned type. So be careful if you are doing a decrement loop.

Comment: "_Can someone explain and provide examples of situations where using size_t would be more beneficial than, let's say, int or uint8_t for array declarations or iteration?_" - Someone can do this, yes!

Answer (score 7):

Match your **type** to your **data**. If you have a counter (that can't be negative) or a length or size, ... then an `unsigned` type makes sense, provides double the range of the same size signed type, etc... For counters, lengths, etc.. the standard C++ sizetype is `size_t`. Can you use other types -- sure. But in general, `size_t` is the preferred sizetype.

If you have an value that is `size_t` and need to iterate over the range, use `size_t` as your loop counter as well, e.g.

```
size_t len = mystring.length();

for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) { ... }
```

If you attempt to use a *signed* loop variable instead, you will generate a *Warning: comparison between signed and unsigned types*.. So match your types as well.

Comment: `unsigned` makes sense, but it bears the danger that user might mess up something in calculations.

Comment: I'm not sure how the mess-up would go, but `size_t` is an unsigned type, see [std::size_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t)

Comment: Say, you have an inner loop till `i-1`. Or takes a difference of unsigned numbers then casts it to double, If the result was meant to be negative...

Comment: Okay, I understand what you are talking now. You are talking about unsigned representation of a negative value resulting in a very large valued (two-compliment), e.g. `size_t t = -1;` yields `t == 18446744073709551615` (where `sizeof (size_t)` is `8-bytes`)

Answer (score 2):

`size_t` is unsigned and large enough to index any container in memory, it's purpose built to use as an index type.

Comment: Perhaps there are better types to help OP with?

Answer (score 2):

While using `size_t` for iteration seems the natural choice, there is at least one pitfall.

Consider the following for-loop:

```
int arr[]{0, 1, 2, 3};
for(size_t i = 3; i >=0; --i) {
    std::cout << i << ": " << arr[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Expected behavior - **at least at first glance**, is to get these 4 lines printed:

```
3: 3
2: 2
1: 1
0: 0
```

What we get instead is something like:

```
3: 3
2: 2
1: 1
0: 0
18446744073709551615: -1
18446744073709551614: -2
18446744073709551613: 32514
18446744073709551612: -41561408
[and so on]
```

That's because `size_t a = 0; --a;` on this particular platform results in `a` being `18446744073709551615`.

On a vague related note, even harder to spot problems can be introduced by [mixing of signed and unsigned types in arithmetic operations](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#arithmetic) and some developers state that using [data type `size_t` causes more problems than it solves](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3493).